# Powershell Silent Install Exe w/o GUI

Tags: powershell, silent-installer

I am trying to write a silent installation in Powershell that installs an exe using the following command:

```
$pathargs = {$exePath /s /v /qn}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $pathargs
```

When I run this however, I'm prompted with this gui:

[image]

Does anyone know how to avoid having this page popup and start the installation?

Comment: Looks like you'll have to [extract the msi from the executable](https://cablespaghetti.github.io/2015/10/28/forticlient-silent-install.html)

Comment: There's an msi available for download from Fortinet support for v5.4, but for your version you'll need to extract it like @MathiasR.Jessen suggests.

Comment: That's weird that it does that. Thanks for you help Mathias!